# Python script having errorr 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_row'

Tags: python, openpyxl, nonetype

need some help on the error that I am getting for my python script. I need to fetch the last row number in my excel work sheet.

Im using `openpyxl==2.5.12`.

Below is the code and error that I am getting.

code :

```
workbook = load_workbook(directory)
ws = workbook.active
max_row = ws.max_row
```

error :
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_row'.`

I saw some past answers to the similar questions. I tried having `Max_row()`, it doesn't work. nrows also doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you load workbook first? post your full code

Comment: some variables.
workbook = load_workbook(directory + "/" + filename)
ws = workbook.active
max_row = ws.max_row

Comment: where have u assigned anything to `ws` ??

Comment: nope you should edit your post and place properly otherwise it is difficult to help

Comment: Your problem is that ``workbook.active`` returns ``None``, not that ``max_row`` is an incorrect name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is nothing to do with `max_row`, the error is saying that there is no `max_row` available on an object which is `NoneType`, which indicates that the line `workbook = load_workbook(directory)` is not working correctly.

I would suggest looking at whatever `directory` is, because it seems to be empty.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! The workbook itself has an issue. Its a wrong file format.

Comment: @YollevTay You may consider accepting the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Form the documentation of [`workbook.active`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#module-openpyxl.workbook.workbook):

> Get the currently active sheet or None

**Your workbook does not have an active sheet.** As a result, `ws = workbook.active` sets `ws` to `None` instead of a worksheet. This causes `ws.max_row` to fail because it only works on worksheets.

You either have to a) fix your workbook so that it does have an active sheet, or b) do not precede if you load a workbook without an active sheet.

```
workbook = load_workbook(directory)
ws = workbook.active
if ws is None:
    return  # or `continue` a loop, `raise` an exception, `sys.exit` the program, ...
max_row = ws.max_row
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys! The workbook itself has an issue. Its a wrong file format.

Comment: @YollevTay Please upvote helpful answers and accept the one best solving your problem.